# Avoid reload of gravity form using gform_confirmation_loaded

Tags: ajax, gravity-forms-plugin

When using gform_confirmation_loaded, is there a way to keep the form showing even after it's been submitted?

So for example, there's an image upload form. In case the user uploads an image smaller in dimensions than the allowed size, an alert box shows telling them about the size restrictions (this can be easily achieved), and the form stays intact to allow the user upload the image again **(the form's got the ajax option enabled)**.

I'm able to achieve something similar to this where the alert box shows and the page reloads showing the form again and enabling the user to reupload the image.

Comment: Show us what you already tried, and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To piggyback off of Alexandre, please post code

Comment: Current Code: http://pastie.org/private/oc2aobihtwk5w9vjsrzlxa

This is what I tried.